# Почему нельзя применить бинарный поиск на неотсортированном списке

Tags: алгоритм

Учу алгоритмы и узнал, что бинарный поиск применяется только к отсортированному списку элементов, но не написано почему нельзя использовать неотсортированный. Можете объяснить почему?

Comment: А как вы представляете себе работу бинарного поиска на неотсортированном списке?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Алгоритм двоичного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) предполагает итеративное деление списка пополам, где на каждом шаге искомый элемент сравнивается со значением среднего элемента в отсортированном списке. Если искомый элемент меньше среднего элемента - значит дальше искать будем в первой половине, если больше, то во второй половине, если равен то мы нашли искомый элемент.

Если список не отсортирован, то невозможно воспользоваться алгоритмом половинного деления, т.к. искомый элемент может оказаться в любой половине списка.